# 404 customisation

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I want to make a custom 404 page.

I created a .htaccess containing only this line :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
```

And the structure of my website is like this :

- errors

  - 404.html
- index.php
- .htaccess
- includes

  - header.html

I always get this erros on the 404 page :

```
Not Found

The requested URL /blabla/bg was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

An idea ? Thank you !

Comment: Case sensitivity of the directory where your custom 404 page resides maybe?

Comment: My fault in the post, the folder is called "errors" without cap

Comment: Then any other `RewriteRule`s before that?

Comment: Similar suggestion: are you sure it's `html` not `htm`. Also you might need to post more of the htaccess file for context; that line should be fine. Are you using a virtual server setup?

Comment: I don't have any RewriteRule before, only the line mentionned. This is not a .htm problem. And i'm on my mamp server.

Comment: Can you post more context? It could be that you put the `ErrorDocument` line in the wrong place, or you might have the folders pointing to the wrong place, or as Havelock suggested you could be overriding it with another rule.

Comment: Also are you sure the htaccess file is even running? Some hosts disable htaccess files.

Comment: How could I be sure my .htaccess is running? But in the error page, the ErrorDocument is mentionned. So I wonder that it's running. And as told before, I don't have any other line in my .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your document root is not equivalent to where your `.htaccess` is. Unfortunately, `ErrorDocument` is not relative to where your `.htaccess` is and instead bases the path on where your document root is (for instance `/var/www/`)

One (kind of hacky) solution I've used in the past to get "relative" 404 Error pages is to do the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.* 404.php [L]
```

The other (and more correct way) to do this is to specify the entire path from the true document root on your server.

To get this full path you'll want to open the 404 page in a browser (and make it a php page in your case so you can get this variable out: `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`  or if you happen to have more knowledge of the setup of your directory structure.  You can base it off of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: Well, you're first method works like a charm. I'll use the second one later, because i'm currently on my localhost and not the final server. Thank you for your answer !